# How to delete posts older than one year with post meta, post attachments and files?

Tags: plugins, functions

Can anybody help me with a function to delete posts older than one year with postmeta, attachements and files?

Tnx

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you would like to do?

Comment: I want to delete all posts older than in example 365 days with all associated data (meta, attachments, files)

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered that type of question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289103/automatically-delete-attachments-and-posts/289243#289243) but you want to delete `post_meta` too. Here is your code. Please test this on `localhost` first.

```php
<?php

// Please use this function carefully.
// Changes can't undone. Best regards from Serkan Algur :)
// Let the function begin
function delete_oldest_posts_salgur()
{
    // We will collect posts from two years ago :)
    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'before' => '2 years ago', // change this definition for your needs
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    // Get posts via WP_Query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    //We are doing this for 'foreach'
    $posts = $query->get_posts();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo $post->ID;
        $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order'          => 'ASC',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image', // only for images. Look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children
                'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            );

        $attachments = get_children($args);
        $post_metas = get_post_meta($post->ID); // Get all post metas

        if ($post_metas) {
            foreach ($post_metas as $key => $pmeta) { //delte all of them
                delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
            }
        }

        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                wp_delete_attachment($attachment->ID, true); //If You Want to trash post set true to false
            }
        }
        wp_delete_post($post->ID, true); //If You Want to trash post set true to false
    }
}

// Problem Solver Cron Job definition
function cron_delete_oldest_posts_salgur()
{
    if (! wp_next_scheduled('delete_oldest_posts_salgur')) {
        wp_schedule_event(current_time('timestamp'), 'daily', 'delete_oldest_posts_salgur');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'cron_delete_oldest_posts_salgur');
```

Answer (score -1):

I find-out an way, when working on a `cron` related project.
1. Install and active `[WP Crontol plugin][1]`
2. Go to Tools->Cron Events.
3. Create new cron job at `Add PHP Cron Event tab. Here, I use PHP code

```
global $wpdb;
$posts_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
$term_relationships_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'term_relationships';
$postmeta_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

$sql = "DELETE a, b, c
FROM $posts_table a
LEFT JOIN $term_relationships_table b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $postmeta_table c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF( NOW(), a.post_date) > 365
";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare($sql) );
```

`now` and `12:00:00` in `Next Run` 
`Once Hourly` in `Recurrence`

4. Save this cron event and click on run now.